# OctoberCMS does not create index

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am creating some database tables in my OctoberCMS plugin, and in these tables I want to use some indexes.
The problem is that these indexes don't get created, de tables get created without the indexes.

```
Schema::create('table', function ($table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('textField')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Why this is/could be?

EDIT: In light of a comment I want to mention that this is not just occurring on text fields but also on integer fields.

Comment: I think TEXT columns do not support these indices. If you are looking for a FULLTEXT index, see here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fulltext-indexes-at-migrations

Comment: Thanks, but i found out its not only the text columns that don't work. When i try to create an index on an integer it doesn't work either. I will use your solution for the text fields though, thank you very much for helping.

Comment: What database system and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
Schema::create('table', function ($table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('textField');
    $table->index(['text_field'])
    $table->timestamps();
});
```